# add image to title of web application in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, image, title

How can I add an image to the title of a web application (something like facebook logo in head title)

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Head_Title" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</head>
```

============================================================================

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Head_Title.ascx.cs" Inherits="Controls_Head_Title" %>


<title>

website
||
<%= title %>

</title>
```

how can I add it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/ico" href="/favicon.ico" />
</head>
```

Create your image as an ICO or PNG (16x16) and put it in your root folder.

Comment: if it doesn't work, probably is your image, where you placed the file, or your webserver. Remember this is not a hack or something, this is the accepted way of adding an ICO for a site.

Answer (score 0):

You should have an icon and link it as below

```
 <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert The Image Into 16X16 pixels (Image which you want See As tittle Image).
2. Only .ico Image will work as a tittle image so convert your image into .ico . For converting visit
   [http://www.favicon.cc/](http://favicon.cc) and import you image and download Fevicon
3. place the image in root folder of your project Ex- /images/Logo.ico
4. use

   > `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/Logo.ico"
   >   type="image/x-icon" />`

   tag in head section of your asp.net page.
5. Your Done...!!!